# Let $p$ be prime and $S = \{(x, y)\in \mathbb{F}_p^2 : y^2 = x^3 - x + 1\}$. Prove that $\mathrm{Card}(S) \leq 2p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

> In fact, $y^2 = x^3 - x + 1$ is an elliptic curve. I have to show that the number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-rational points on this curve is at most $2p$.

What I know is that for an elliptic curve $E : y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$, $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has at most $2p+1$ points. By Hasse's Theorem $\mathrm{Card}(E(\mathbb{F}_p)) = p+1-a_p(E)$ with $\left| a_p(E) \right| \leq 2\sqrt{p}$. But I am not sure if this could help me to solve my problem. Moreover, consider the set $S= \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2 \mid y^2 = x^3\}$. How can I show that $\mathrm{Card}(S) = p$ for any prime $p$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you including the point at infinity? If not then this is easy:
each $x$ value determines at most two $y$ values. If you are, then Hasse
is certainly strong enough. But for an elementary proof... all the values
of $x^3-x+1$ would have to be quadratic residues for a counter-example, but I don't see any down-to-earth reason why this can't be true.

By the way, $y^2=x^3$ is not an elliptic curve. It is parametrised by
$(x,y)=(t^2,t^3)$ though.

Comment: Sorry! You are absolutely right that $y^2 = x^3$ is not an elliptic curve. What I actually was interested to know is why the cardinality of the set $S = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^2 : y^2 = x^3\}$ is exactly $p$ for any prime $p$. For instance, if I consider $\mathbb{F}_{3} = \{0, 1, 2\}$, then $S = \{(0, 0), (1, 1)\}$ contains $2$ points, but not $3$. So I do not really understand why $Card(S) = p$ for any prime $p$ should be true.

Comment: @Crystal You mean $S=\{(0,0),(1,1),(1,2)\}$.

Comment: It seems that I am a little bit confused today. In fact, I forgot to take the points mod $p$. I see now that it is obviously true. But thank you very much for your answer. It was helpful :).